# Path некорректно отображает слэши

Tags: java, строки, path

Всем привет.

Есть у меня String: "http://localhost:8080/image-resource/1/17/21/table_image_491572592.jpg"

При попытке получить из него Path съедается один слэш:

```
    String s = "http://localhost:8080/image-resource/1/17/21/table_image_491572592.jpg";
    Path path = Paths.get(s);
```

Path:

```
http:/localhost:8080/image-resource/1/17/21/table_image_491572592.jpg
```

Как корректно получить Path из String?

P.S. Решил тащить через URI:

```
    String s = "http://localhost:8080/image-resource/1/17/21/table_image_491572592.jpg";
    URI uri = URI.create(s);
    Path path = Paths.get(uri);
```

Валится со следующим стектрейсом:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "http" not installed
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:147)
```

ну и так далее.

Comment: Может быть стоит использовать `URI` или `URL` классы, если у вас URL в строке?

Comment: Приведите решение на данном примере, пожалуйста.

Comment: Где у вас дальше используется этот экземпляр `Path`? `Path` предназначен для хранения путей в файловых системах всё-таки.

Comment: Я потом по этому Path вытаскиваю файл через InputStream: InputStream resourceAsStream = Files.newInputStream(path);

Comment: Думаю, `new URL("http:// ...").openStream()` поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог совет Алекса Черменина.

```
new URL("http:// ...").openStream()
```